# How can I dynamically select things using ScrollView?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am trying to create a view that is used to filter results. I want to be able to tap or scroll to select the Category.

There should be a line underneath the selected category to indicate it is selected.

The length of the line should be dynamic to match the length of the title of the category.

The needs to act as a magnet, so that it the line always locks onto the nearest Category when stopping the scroll.

I tried using an offset for the line but couldn't get it right, and im unsure on how to make the line (which is to part of CategoryButton) to select the categories.

Here is an example of it in airbnb app.
https://imgur.com/a/ltgS9RA

Here is my code that I have now:

```
import SwiftUI

struct Category: Identifiable, Equatable {
    let id = UUID()
    let title: String
    let color: Color
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    let categories: [Category] = [
        Category(title: "Red", color: .red),
        Category(title: "Green", color: .green),
        Category(title: "Blue", color: .blue),
        Category(title: "Yellow", color: .yellow),
        Category(title: "Orange", color: .orange),
        Category(title: "Purple", color: .purple)
    ]
    
    @State private var selectedCategory: Category = Category(title: "Red", color: .red)
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                    HStack(spacing: 20) {
                        ForEach(categories, id: \.id) { category in
                            CategoryButton(category: category, isSelected: category == selectedCategory)
                                .onTapGesture {
                                    withAnimation {
                                        selectedCategory = category
                                    }
                                }
                        }
                    }
                    .padding(.horizontal, 20)
                }
                // Line to indicate selected category
                Capsule()
                    .frame(width: 25, height: 5) // Make this dynamic
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                    .padding(.leading, 30)
                
            }
            // Circle that changes colour dependning on what is selected
            Circle()
                .frame(width: 70, height: 70)
                .foregroundColor(selectedCategory.color)
                .offset(y: 50)
            
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}

struct CategoryButton: View {
    let category: Category
    let isSelected: Bool

    var body: some View {
        Text(category.title)
            .font(.headline)
            .padding(10)
            .cornerRadius(8)
    }
}


#Preview {
    ContentView()
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works quite well to use `.matchedGeometryEffect` for moving the line to the selected button.

However, `selectedCategory` needs to refer to one of the categories in the array when first launched. Two ways of achieving this would be:

- make the id of a category predictable, such as, use the title as the id
- or, define the array of categories as a static array.

Taking the approach of a static  array, the array could also be moved into the `Category` struct itself. I added some more colours too:

```swift
struct Category: Identifiable, Equatable {
    let id = UUID()
    let title: String
    let color: Color

    static let allCategories: [Category] = [
        Category(title: "Red", color: .red),
        Category(title: "Green", color: .green),
        Category(title: "Blue", color: .blue),
        Category(title: "Yellow", color: .yellow),
        Category(title: "Orange", color: .orange),
        Category(title: "Purple", color: .purple),
        Category(title: "Mint", color: .mint),
        Category(title: "Teal", color: .teal),
        Category(title: "Pink", color: .pink),
        Category(title: "Brown", color: .brown),
        Category(title: "Indigo", color: .indigo)
    ]
}
```

After that, you just need to add `.matchedGeometryEffect` to the buttons in the `ScrollView` and to the capsule that you want to see moving. Some notes:

- a namespace is needed for the effect
- the id of a category is also used as the id for the `matchedGeometryEffect`
- the flag `isSource` can only be true for one element at a time, this should be the button corresponding to the selected category
- the size and position of the capsule is determined by the target button, padding is not needed
- the height of the capsule can be constrained using `.frame(maxHeight: 5)`.

Some other simplifications can be made at the same time:

- the struct `Category` implements `Identifiable`, so it is not necessary to identify the `id` for the `ForEach`
- the nested `VStack` with `.leading` alignment is not needed.

Also, to move the coloured circle down, I would suggest using padding instead of setting an offset. This way, the circle is shown at its true position in the layout, instead of being moved from its true position.

Here's how it all comes together:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var selectedCategory: Category = Category.allCategories.first!
    @Namespace private var nsCategories

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
                HStack(spacing: 20) {
                    ForEach(Category.allCategories) { category in
                        CategoryButton(category: category, isSelected: category == selectedCategory)
                            .matchedGeometryEffect(id: category.id, in: nsCategories, isSource: selectedCategory == category)
                            .onTapGesture {
                                selectedCategory = category
                            }
                    }
                }
                .padding(.horizontal, 20)
            }
            // Line to indicate selected category
            Capsule()
                .foregroundColor(.black)
                .frame(maxHeight: 5)
                .matchedGeometryEffect(id: selectedCategory.id, in: nsCategories, isSource: false)
                .animation(.easeInOut, value: selectedCategory)

            // Circle that changes colour depending on what is selected
            Circle()
                .frame(width: 70, height: 70)
                .foregroundColor(selectedCategory.color)
                .padding(.top, 50)

            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Animation]

The other part (actually, the main part) of the question was about auto-selecting a new category when the categories are scrolled. One way to do this is to associate a `GeometryReader` with each button and use an `.onChange` handler to change the selection as soon as the button for the current selection is no longer fully in view.

These changes are needed to the code above:

1. Add a function that can be called to switch to the previous or the next category:

```swift
private func switchCategory(toPrevious: Bool) {
    if let index = Category.allCategories.firstIndex(of: selectedCategory) {
        if toPrevious && index > 0 {
            selectedCategory = Category.allCategories[index - 1]
        } else if !toPrevious && index < Category.allCategories.count - 1 {
            selectedCategory = Category.allCategories[index + 1]
        }
    }
}
```

2. Name the coordinate space of the `ScrollView` and nest the `ScrollView` in a `GeometryReader`, so that the width of the view can be determined.

- A `GeometryReader` is greedy and grabs all the space available. To keep the appearance similar to before, apply a `maxHeight`.
- The namespace that is being used for the `matchedGeometryEffect` can be re-used for naming the coordinate space of the `ScrollView`.

```swift
GeometryReader { outer in
    let viewWidth = outer.size.width
    ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
        // content as before
    }
}
.frame(maxHeight: 20)
.coordinateSpace(name: nsCategories)
```

3. Add a `GeometryReader` to the background of each button and add an `onChange` handler to perform a change of selection, as described above

```swift
CategoryButton(category: category, isSelected: category == selectedCategory)
    .matchedGeometryEffect(id: category.id, in: nsCategories, isSource: selectedCategory == category)
    .onTapGesture {
        // as before
    }
    .background {
        GeometryReader { proxy in
            let pos = proxy.frame(in: .named(nsCategories))
            let relativePosition = pos.minX >= 0 && pos.maxX <= viewWidth
                ? 0
                : pos.minX < 0 ? -1 : 1
            Color.clear
                // pre iOS 17: .onChange(of: relativePosition) { newVal in
                .onChange(of: relativePosition) { oldVal, newVal in
                    if selectedCategory == category && newVal != 0 {
                        switchCategory(toPrevious: newVal > 0)
                    }
                }
        }
    }
```

This shows it all working:

[image: AnimationWithScroll]

Comment: Answer updated to include elaboration of auto-selection.

Comment: this is a great answer thank you! However for my project the deployment target is iOS 15. Is there an alternative I can use for this? The .onChange and .coordinateSpace have parts that require iOS 17

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I am quite confused as to how to implement the changes for earlier versions, do you mind providing a code block of the full code for earlier versions?

Comment: I changed the .onChanged to the updated one, removed the .coordinateSpace however I am still getting an iOS 17 required error on this part:  let pos = proxy.frame(in: .scrollView). here is the error: 'frame(in:)' is only available in iOS 17.0 or newer

Comment: thanks this works on earlier versions! There is one small bug where sometimes the scrolling doesn't change the category or changes the to previous one by mistake. It tends to happen if you scroll slower but has happened when scrolled fast once I think. Not a big issue but have you got any ideas on what's causing that behaviour? It seems to be an issue on the first 4 category buttons (Red to Yellow)

Comment: @Schwifty I think it's working now for earlier versions, points 2 + 3 of answer updated to use other versions of the modifiers. The version of `.onChange` needed for earlier iOS versions is shown in a comment. Hopefully, the problem with the selection going the wrong way when scrolling slowly is also fixed: the definition of `relativePosition` needs to use `>=` and `<=` instead of `>` and `<` (code for point 3 updated once more). Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: thanks! This looks to be working now. When I implement this code in an entirely separate project that has other things going on, the animation bugs out, I assume its something in that other project interfering with it, have you got any ideas on how to make the smooth animations that are already there avoid interference from other code?

Comment: @Schwifty It might help *not* to use `withAnimation` when changing `selectedCategory`. Instead, just apply an `.animation` modifier to the `Capsule`. I have updated the code in this way, there were 2 cases of `withAnimation` which can simply be removed. You might want to view the delta for the edit if it's not clear.

Comment: @Nenzy Neez, perfect! That's a great solution, thank you!